# C# private void to public static void

Tags: c#

I am making my first steps with C# and I am struggling with moving a void from private to public static.

This is my code from the "Button click" void

```
DataColumn col = Files.dt.Columns["Pfad"];
foreach (DataRow row in Files.dt.Rows)
{
    OleDocumentProperties myFile = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
    myFile.Open(@"" + row[col] + "", false, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
    foreach (DSOFile.CustomProperty property in myFile.CustomProperties)
        if (property.Name == "Überarbeitet")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Gefunden");
        }
    myFile.Close();
}
```

Because I would like to call this void from other Buttons to I decided to move it to my

```
public class SpecialFunctions
{
}
```

The other stuff is working really good but this one is making me crazy. I can't access the `Files(dataset) + dt (datatable)`. It is probably something really easy but I don't get it :/

Comment: Please edit your question and add where you declare the dataset and datatable. Your problem is most likely that both are instance members (non-static)

Comment: just as a tip to make shure you don't make little mistakes, put `{ and }` after your `foreach` around the whole `if` statement.

Comment: All variables you want to access inside a `static` method must either be static themselves, be constants or be passed as parameter.

Comment: @all 

thank you for your effort. Gonna do the things with the brackets right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void SpecialFuntion_1(DataTable table) 
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) 
    {
        OleDocumentProperties myFile = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
        myFile.Open($"{row[col]}", 
                    false,
                    DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
        foreach (DSOFile.CustomProperty property in myFile.CustomProperties)
        {
            if (property.Name == "Überarbeitet") 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gefunden");
            }
        }
        myFile.Close();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
this.SpecialFuntion_1(Files.dt);
```

Comment: Guessing `foreach (DataRow row in Files.dt.Rows)` should be `foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)`.

Comment: Great, this solved my problem and gives me an idea how to solve the other small problems, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When you alter the access modifier from non-static to `static`, you're changing the way in which the member is available. For example, if it was instance-based before, when you add the `static` access modifier it can only access other `static` members.

As an option, you could take on the instance variables as parameters into a method, then the argument from the click events would be the method scoped variables. Imagine a `SpecialFunctions` class like below:

```
public static class SpecialFunctions
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithInstanceVariable(DataSet files, DataTable myFile)
    {
        var col = files.dt.Columns["Pfad"];
        foreach (DataRow row in Files.dt.Rows)
        {
            var myFile = new DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties();
            myFile.Open(@"" + row[col] + "", false, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
            foreach (DSOFile.CustomProperty property in myFile.CustomProperties)
                if (property.Name == "Überarbeitet")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Gefunden");
                }
            myFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would assume your click event would be something like this:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pass in instance data set / table variables to static method.
    SpecialFunctions.DoSomethingWithInstanceVariable(this.Files, this.MyFile);
}
```